# What URL should I go to to create my simpleDB domain?

Tags: amazon-simpledb

I can't figure out where I can go create a domain for my simpleDB.
I've gone to AWS Management Console, I was able to create a **bucket** for S3, but I don't have a simple DB tab.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SimpleDB is not yet supported by AWS console. They may eventually add it, but for now you have to use direct service calls (with SDK it is the easiest).

Comment: There are also some reasonably nice UI tools to access it. I don't remember on top of my head but they should be easily found via Google.

Comment: This one for example: http://aws.amazon.com/code/1137?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

Answer (score 2):

SDB Tool is a great FOSS Firefox plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/sdbtool/

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDB Explorer. SDB Explorer  has been made as an industry leading graphical user interface (GUI) to explore Amazon SimpleDB  service thoroughly and in a very efficient and user friendly way.

http://www.sdbexplorer.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Javascript Scratchpad for Amazon SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1137?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're a Python lover, try out `boto` library, designed to access AWS resources. Find more information here: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/simpledb_tut.html